# Prevent tearing of environment

Tags: formatting, code

I have a custom environment, called `test`. The text placed in the environment should be kept together, even when placed in a `multicol` environment, i.e. if written as the following code

```
OtherText
\begin{test}
A
B
C
D
\end{test}
```

normally it would look like (if placed in a 2-column multicol environment)

```
OtherText   C
A           D
B
```

but I would rather have as a result (if it is not possible to get everything into the first column):

```
OtherText A
          B
          C
          D
```

My first approach was adding a minipage environment, i.e.:

```
\newenvironment{test}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}{\end{minipage}}
```

but that collided with the `multicol`-option, generating overlapping text, thus only usable for one-column text. Is there another alternative?

Comment: Replacing `\textwidth` with `\linewidth` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\textwidth` is the width of the printing area, not the column width. Use `\linewidth` instead, which is the *current* line width.

(Similarly, in a table, when a `\multirow` is inserted in a `X` column, you can specify the current  X column width as the multirow width using `multirow{number of  rows}{\linewidth}{…}`).